# PyQt5 - Python | QApplication.setStyle not working

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, qapplication

I am trying to set custom style to my PyQt5 application using the `setStyle()` method but it doesn't work.

I am also not entirely sure about where this should be put.

In my main I tried doing :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    QApplication.setStyle("mac") #here
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    splash_pix = QPixmap('../resource/logo.png')
    start = time.time()
    splash = QSplashScreen(splash_pix, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    splash.show()
    while time.time() - start < 1:
        time.sleep(0.003)
        app.processEvents()
    ex = Fy360()
    splash.finish(ex)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Edit : Upon importing `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleFactory` and printing the `QStyleFactory.keys()` I gotthe output as:

`[u'Windows', u'Fusion']`

why are there only these options?

*Whats going wrong here?*

Comment: You can run the following command: `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleFactory;
print(QStyleFactory.keys())` and show us what you

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry for the late reply, I did as you said but I got no output!. what does that mean?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm sorry I did a mistake, I tried to print the keys in a function hence I got no output but when I tried it in my main I got this `[u'Windows', u'Fusion']
`

Comment: Those are the styles you can use. What is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc Linux, Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: can Install some extra package to enable other styles?

Comment: Some styles are dependent on the OS, others are not, for example the Mac style is only for Mac OS, or for example fusion is compatible for several OS.

Comment: @eyllanesc okay, Thank you! one last thing. both available options make the app look out of place in my themed Ubuntu. Any way to make the application inherit the enabled theme?

Comment: What is your theme?

Comment: @eyllanesc  adapta theme

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried setting the `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE`to gtk and gtk+ with no result

Comment: install qt5ct: https://launchpad.net/~mati75/+archive/ubuntu/qt5ct

Comment: or this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/breeze

Comment: @eyllanesc finally solved it by installing `qt5ct`  and  `qt5-style-plugins` I had to set `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` in my /etc/environment file too. Then I simply chose gtk2 in qt5ct  Do you mind summing up the whole thing as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some styles are dependent on the OS, others are not, for example the Mac style is only for Mac OS, or for example fusion is compatible for several OS.

Some styles (for example **gtk**) can be configured as follows:

Based on the [discussion](https://github.com/manjaro/release-plan/issues/73) :

- Install `qt5-styleplugins` and `qt5ct`
- Set environment variable in **/etc/environment** `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct`
- Restart the system
- Start `qt5ct` and select `gtk2`